# Iteration and replace through double array

Tags: python

Having this array:

```
a = [1, None, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, None, 7]
```

I need to replace the values of None for 0. My first implementation is to go trough the array, but I want to do it in one line.

I tried something like this, but didn't work:

```
a = [0 if value is None else value for value in a[i][1] for i in range(len(a))]
```

Obviously is not working, what would be the right approach?

Edit: I don't want to touch the other positions, just the second position of every element in the array.

This:

```
a = [None, None, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, None, 7]
```

Will return this:

```
a = [None, 0, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 0, 7]
```

Comment: How deep can your nesting go?

Comment: Just that, not deeper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> a = [[1, None, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, None, 7]]
>>> [[0 if x is None else x for x in sublist] for sublist in a]
[[1, 0, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 0, 7]]
```

Or an alternative approach where you are only looking at the second item in each sublist:

```
>>> [x[:1] + ([0] if x[1] is None else x[1:2]) + x[2:] for x in a]
[[1, 0, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 0, 7]]
```

Comment: I only need to evaluate the values in the second position of a

Comment: I am assuming you mean the second position of each sublist, my edit should work in that case.

Answer (score 3):

Using `or`:

```
>>> a = [[1, None, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, None, 7]]
>>> [[x or 0 for x in l] for l in a]
[[1, 0, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 0, 7]]
```

Or if you only want to evaluate the second element:

```
>>> a = [[1, None, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, None, 7]]
>>> [[l[0], l[1] or 0] + l[2:] for l in a]
[[1, 0, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 0, 7]]
```

Comment: I only need to evaluate the values in the second position of a

Answer (score 1):

Nested list comprehensions will do it:

```
>>> a = [1, None, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, None, 7]
>>> [[c if c is not None else 0 for c in b] for b in a]
[[1, 0, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 0, 7]]
>>>
```

Comment: I only need to evaluate the values in the second position of a